# std::string_view complexity for constant strings

Tags: c++

I am developing libraries with tons of static strings inside. To optimize the runtime a bit, this shall be changed from null-terminated strings (classic C-style char arrays) to pre-known-length structures, like `std::string` or `std::string_view` or custom pointer+length-pairs. `std::string` is well known and versatile but has the disadvantage of heavy footprint (at least 32bit on x64) plus VM overhead (heap and runtime cost) if the Small-String-Optimization is not applicable, which hits most of my data. `string_view` sounds like the best candidate, as long as I can be sure that data is null-terminated (despite of no such guarantee from `string_view` itself, the risk can be mitigated by conventions).

The questions which still matters much: do modern compilers pre-initialize `string_view` without using internal `strlen`, i.e. with constant complexity and not O^(n)? If they do, is the null-terminator preserved?

I could, of course, add some macro to initialize the `string_views` but that would be cumbersome. Something like:

```
#define foo(buf) foo, (sizeof(foo)-1)
const string_view svMyVar(foo("original C-string value"));
```

**I hope that compiler would simplify that for me.**

Comment: did you mean to write `#define foo(buf) buf, (sizeof(buf)-1)` ?

Comment: You could also store as `char const str[] = "foobar";` which lets the compiler determine the size of the array, and you can query that via the type system. This in theory allows a ctor `string_view(char(&)[N])` which would be guaranteed to compute the string "length" at compile time, but there's no such ctor in the stdlib.

Comment: Other than that, there's `"foobar"sv` which uses user-defined literals, where again, the compiler knows the string length and just passes that to a function `operator""(char const*, size_t)`. On top of all that, you can have `constexpr string_view x = ...;` which should be initialized by any reasonable optimizing compiler at compile-time.

Comment: You can play around a bit here: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/bc6s847Pr As expected, `constexpr` causes compile-time string length "computation" even w/o optimizations, and mutable block-scope `string_view` get their string length computation resolved at compile time at `-O1` already. using the `sv` user-defined literal also gets the length resolved at compile-time w/o optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `std::string_view(const char*)` constructor has linear complexity, it is a `constexpr` constructor and a string literal is a compile time constant, and optimisers are often able to perform the linear complexity at compile time in practice, making the runtime constant. In constant evaluation contexts, this is guaranteed.

Note that your suggested macro, as well as the template suggested in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67003747/2079303) behave differently from `std::string_view(const char*)` because string literals may contain null terminators, and the constructor only extends until the first terminator while the macro extends the entire literal.

This is particularly problematic if used with a non-string literal array that contains uninitialised elements that have garbage values:

```
const string_view svMyVar1("test\0test");
// svMyVar1.size() == 4

const string_view svMyVar2(foo("test\0test"));
// svMyVar2.size() == 9

char arr[32];
arr[0] = 'a';
arr[1] = '\0';
// arr now contains a null terminated "a" followed by 30 garbage chars
const string_view svMyVar3(foo(arr));
// svMyVar3.size() == 31, contains garbage
```

> If they do, is the null-terminator preserved?

String view doesn't modify the array that it refers to. If the referred array contains a null terminator after the referred string, then the null terminator remains there. If there isn't a null terminator, then no null terminator is added.

Reading `svMyVar[svMyVar.size()]` still has undefined behaviour even if there is a null terminator outside the bounds of the view.

On the other hand, reading `*(svMyVar.data() + svMyVar.size())` is fine if you know that there is a null terminator (or any other character) there. You cannot rely on that being the case in general with string view, but you can rely on it if the view is created from a string literal which is guaranteed to be null terminated.

---

> without using internal strlen

Compilers are smart enough to calculate even `strlen("literal")` at compile time.

Technically, `std::string_view` uses `Traits::length` interanally, not `std::strlen`.

Comment: I am aware of the potentially different behavior in case where null-terminator is part of the char array but this is certainly not a subject for concern here. I have seen literals mentioned somewhere in the docs already but was never fully sure how exactly they are supposed to work - and I can imagine a compiler which massages the data for optimization, stripping the terminator, therefore my question question.

Comment: @PasterOfMuppets Then the most useful part of my answer to you is *"string literal which is guaranteed to be null terminated`"*.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) doesn't have constructor taking `const char (&) [N]` but only (related to `const char*`) `const char*` or `const char*, std::size_t size`.
The former has to compute length, the later is given.

Instead of a MACRO, you might have function

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::string_view make_string_view(const char* (&s)[N]) { return {s, N - 1}; }
```

[operator ""sv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv) might even be simpler (size is also known/used at compile time to construct the `string_view`):

- `"hello world"sv`

Note that you might include `\0` if you want:

- `"hello world\0"sv`

Comment: there is no need to append \0, as the user defined literal points at a string literal, which like any other string literal is nul terminated.

Comment: But that (normal) `\0` would be outside of the range of the span.

Comment: Indeed, I now see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) that for user-defined literals, "_`len` is the length of the string literal, **excluding the terminating null character**_", and your factory function also removes the terminating NUL (or other terminating character if it didn't point at a string literal but just some 'other' `char*`)